How to create a PayPal donation form or webpage (not a button)?
All I find seems to be how to make a button that opens a new browser window on PayPal’s website. How do I create a form for an embed or iframe to place into a webpage on my own website?

paypal's own faq on the topic

PayPal's donate SDK uses a minibrowser for donation approval, rather than redirecting away from your site. Perhaps it's what you're looking for https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/donate/
